# How to get input with assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm learning 8086 assembly and I have to do a login screen that asks for a UserName and a Password, from the user. After the user enter his data, I have to check if it correct. My code is:

```
DATA SEGMENT 
N=11

STRING DB "Wellcom, please Enter your",10,13,"UserNmae: ",8,'$'    
STRING2 DB 10,13, "PassWord: ",8,'$' 

BUFFER  DW  10,?,11 DUP(?)
BUFFER2  DW  10,?,11 DUP(?)   

NAME_OF_USER DW ?
NAME_OF_SYSTEM DW "DARIO"

DATA ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT STACK

DW 100 DUP (?)

SSEG ENDS


CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE ,DS:DATA SS:SSEG
START: MOV AX,DATA
   MOV DS,AX

     MOV DX,OFFSET STRING        ;PUTS THE FIRST SRTING 
     MOV AH,9
     INT 21H 

     CALL EnterName
     CALL EnterPassword  




EXIT: MOV AH,4CH
      INT 21H              



  EnterName PROC

     MOV DX,OFFSET BUFFER    ; GETS  THE NAME 
    mov NAME_OF_USER,DX     
     MOV AH,10
     INT 21H
    RET 

EnterName ENDP



EnterPassword PROC

     MOV DX,OFFSET STRING2 ;PRINTS THE CONNTINUE OF THE STRING
     MOV AH,9
     INT 21H
     MOV BX,OFFSET BUFFER2   ;GETS THE PASSWORD
     MOV AH,10
     INT 21H
    RET 

EnterPassword ENDP

CODE ENDS
END START
```

I want to check if the user gives a correct user name. How do I put his input into the *NAME_OF_USER* variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BUFFER  DW  10,?,11 DUP(?)
BUFFER2  DW  10,?,11 DUP(?)

NAME_OF_SYSTEM DW "DARIO"
```

You defined both input structures and the name of the system with the wrong directive! You need to use the `DB` directive.

```
BUFFER         DB  10,?,11 DUP(?)
BUFFER2        DB  10,?,11 DUP(?)

NAME_OF_SYSTEM DB "DARIO",13
```

The instruction `mov NAME_OF_USER,DX` only moves the address of the input structure in the *NAME_OF_USER* variable.
You could of course copy the characters of this name but this would be pointless since you can always use them there where they were inputted. The name resides at **BUFFER+2**.

Here's a simple (use of capitals on input is mandatory) routine to verify if the inputted name equals the name of the system:

```
 mov si, offset NAME_OF_SYSTEM
 mov di, offset BUFFER+2
Next:
 mov al, [si]
 cmp al, [di]
 jne NotTheSame
 inc si
 inc di
 cmp al, 13
 jne Next
TheSame:
 ...
NotTheSame:
 ...
```